# macOS freezes. keyboard/mouse input is registered. screen freezes

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, performance

I am on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Macbook Pro 15" w/ Retina display, mid-2015.

The OS seems to freeze sometimes:

- the screen freezes
- all output sounds freeze (most of the time now, but didn't use to)
- most keyboard/trackpad input is registered, and all gets displayed at once when the screen unfreezes and sounds resume
- sometimes only some keyboard input is registered, or only some trackpad input (or none)

This happens seemingly at random moments, and never seems to last longer than half a minute.

How do I stop this from happening?

I'm not sure how to begin diagnosing the problem, please ask for more info that you need.

It will be tricky for me to record/time etc. the incidents because I can't predict them.